# how do I get a confidence interval in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I know this question has been asked before, but not using this argument as I'm trying to do. I am not seeing the confidence intervals on my data, despite the fact that I think they should be there based on the code I used (from the R cookbook). My code is as follows:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = clawregression_data, aes(x = logDR, y = Deut), shape=1) +    
  geom_smooth(data = newDRdata, aes(x = logDR, y = response), method = lm) +
  expand_limits(y=c(-100,0))
```

It is my understanding that method = lm defaults to se = TRUE, which is what I need to get the confidence intervals. Just in case, I have tried adding se = TRUE after method = lm to see if it helps, and it doesn't change the graph. The graph I'm getting either way looks like this with no resulting confidence intervals:
[image]

and I am going for something more like this with the confidence intervals indicated:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your data - or some simulated data - so we can try to recreate your problem? Is `newDRdata` the predicted output of a prior `lm` model by any chance? In which case the standard error of the error-free predictions would be zero, so `geom_smooth` hasn't got anything to plot.

Comment: Try replacing the line with just `geom_smooth(method = lm)` and see if it gets you what you're looking for.

Comment: Agreed with Andy - if you want confidence intervals for the `clawregression_data` data, then you need to give that data to `geom_smooth()`. It's suspicious that you're instead using `newDRdata` in the `geom_smooth()` layer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Your responses made me aware that I need a stronger understanding of what I'm actually trying to do, so I'm working on that for now.